# pull a face in shock?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, british-english, writing

What's the correct expression? I'm not a native speaker. I want to describe that he made a expression of shock; like pulled a face in shock; but I feel that's wrong. How can I see it concisely?

Answer (score -1):

> like *pulled a face in shock*; but I feel that's wrong.

It is. It does not say what sort of face he pulled, and that is needed because we need to know what has caused the shock - revulsion? Horror? Surprise? Delight?

Assume that his friend has just been shot dead: "His face registered the shock." "His face contorted with shock."

"Pulled a face" is informal and is likely only to be used with minor causes.

Comment: I wouldn't bet anybody knows what *pull a face* means.

Comment: @tchrist - It's a perfectly normal expression to me, but you 'pull a face' to make people laugh or when you taste something unpleasant, not to express shock at a serious event.

Comment: @tchrist It's quite common in BE, OED:  P2. With reference to facial expression: to make (also pull) a face: to distort the features in a grimace (sometimes with modifying word). -- 1980 O. Clark Diary 11 Aug. (1998) 105 *Jerry..pulled a face and later said, ‘Every time I see her she slaps another writ or sues me.’*-- 2007   Wired May 65/3   *‘What do you think’? she asks. ‘Owah’! I say, and make a face.*

Comment: aka make a face

Comment: To me _pull a face_  suggests that the person is intentionally making that face, for effect, or even for a joke, rather than that it is a natural reaction to whatever has happened.

Comment: Downvoted because this answer says definitively "it's wrong" when it may be simply inadvisable. The comment quoting sources shows that we can say that someone "made/pulled a face" without specifying the expression, leaving it to context and imagination, or simply noting that it wasn't the normal facial expression.